# Can't request region for resource

Tags: system-installation

[image]

I have already tried every bios setting and everything I could find online including on this website.

This is my pc: [Asus ROG-GL502VM](https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-GL502VM/)